# Configuring logback to roll on size but not on date

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm struggling to configure logback. This should be trivial to do but it's not.
I want to roll logs on size but not on time. At the same time I would like to keep rolled logs with a name that reflects a date of roll.
I want to keep all history of the logs so FixedWindowRollingPolicy does not work here.

At the moment I'm using

```
    <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>log/my.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-5level %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}  %-40.40thread %-5.5(Inv%X{context}) %-30.30(%method\(\)) %msg      \(%class{0}.java:%line\)%n</pattern>
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>log/mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>all</level>
    </filter>
</appender>
```

Which rolls both on size and every month. I would like to use specified pattern for gz archives.

Thanks.

UPDATE
Added as suggested

```
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
```

I set size size limit to 10MB to see tolling in action
Now I'm getting

```
14:11:57,601 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[ROLLING] - Appender [ROLLING] failed to append. java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.NullPointerException
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.FileFilterUtil.afterLastSlash(FileFilterUtil.java:46)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy.rollover(TimeBasedRollingPolicy.java:149)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.attemptRollover(RollingFileAppender.java:158)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.rollover(RollingFileAppender.java:137)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:178)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(OutputStreamAppender.java:103)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:88)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:48)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:273)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:260)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:442)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_1(Logger.java:414)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Logger.java:604)
at  at my.util.LoggingTesting.main(LoggingTesting.java:21)
```

To me it looks like ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy violates single responibility principle. Rolling policy suppose to configure how logs are rolled but in this case you can specify trigger as well (via timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy)

Answer (score 0):

Try `ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy` instead.

Dont change `rolling policy` just use `<triggeringPolicy>` tag